# DIfferent results in local and live server nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have written an algorithm in nodejs, database I am using is MySQL, and both local and live server database is same and algorithm code in both local and live server is the same. but both are producing different results.

I know this is a weird issue but I am stuck into the problem. I just want to know if the issue could be at MySQL end or what?

if anyone faces the same issues in their then kindly help me to fix.

Comment: The first thing comes to my mind is the data is different in both environments. If you can please give details, it will be easier to diagnose the issue

Comment: show details. sample code, observed results, expected results.

Comment: I have inspect all the data is same at both phpmyadmin live and local, and both files have same code at both end. I have inpect the time zones of both my local and live server and both seems to be same now. UTC... But I still wonder why results are being different.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1fy9tjwu/2/

Comment: Please review the code if you can.

Comment: another thing that comes to the mind is that I have'nt use await function in all my custom functions. But I have tried modified my code with  aysnc and await functions also. But it will not produce the correct results. as results in the localhost is perfect I dont want the result to be different with aysnc and await